# positioning a rotated 90deg element isn't responsive

Tags: html, css, flexbox, rotation, css-transforms

I have this project, with this navbar
[image]

> like you see I am using `flexbox`, and it is correctly viewed.

but they tell me that I need that the navbar is rotated, and the text be viewed like so:

- rotated 90deg.
- hover working fine with the same rotation.
- the black line at the bottom should be on the right side.

something like this (this is only photoshopped image for you, so you can understand):

[image]

and for you can seem easy but I know some CSS, and I know how to rotate it

by using:

```
   transform: rotate(90deg);
```

**but here is the problem, *isn't positioned correctly.***

> so before I will tell you the problems, I will put you my first code without rotating (so it will be easier to you to debug with the next following code)

```css
:root {
  --height: 3rem;
  --triangle-width: 1rem;
  --bg: #ccc;
  --angle: 20deg;
  --text-color: black;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  gap: var(--triangle-width);
  color: var(--text-color);
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 var(--triangle-width);
}

nav::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  background: var(--text-color);
  height: 0.2rem;
  width: 100%;
}

nav div {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  height: var(--height);
  width: calc(100% - (var(--triangle-width) * 2));
  position: relative;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

nav div:hover {
  background-color: var(--bg);
}

nav div:hover::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: calc(-1 * (var(--triangle-width) / 2));
  height: var(--height);
  width: var(--triangle-width);
  background-color: var(--bg);
  transform: skewX(calc(-1 * var(--angle)));
}

nav div:hover::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: calc(-1 * (var(--triangle-width) / 2));
  height: var(--height);
  width: var(--triangle-width);
  background-color: var(--bg);
  transform: skewX(var(--angle));
}

nav div::before,
nav div::after {
  z-index: -1;
}

nav::before {
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div>instagram</div>
  <div>microsoft</div>
  <div>facebook</div>
  <div>linkedin</div>
  <div>youtube</div>
</nav>
```

> the snippet you see up here is the normal flex navbar without rotating

**list of problems**

- the half element is invisible, and seems to overflow

[image]

- is not in its place, like I want (seems to be centered, but I want that it will be on the left side)

[image]

- if I expand the height is not changing, but if I change the width is changing.

> I want that if is rotated, the width of the nav is the height of the device.  
> so if the device is smaller remains the same as the viewport width is higher... but the difference happens only if the height changes.

here are some examples:

> small width 
> [image]

> bigger width 
> [image]

as you see there is some gaps that change a lot, I just want it will be responsive like the code without `transform: rotate(90deg)`

---

---

now that you know the problem, I will tell how I tried to solve it

I used this code:
[image]

```css
transform: translate(45vw, 45vw);
```

that seems to solve something, but only on 900px exactly width of the viewport

[image]

so I need to use a lot `@media` to make it work :(

here an example:

> 500px 
> the text is smaller, no gaps 
> [image]

> 300px 
> the black line of the border disappears completely, the text hasn't any gap between 
> [image]

> 1500px 
> the gaps are much bigger, the black line is moving to the right, most of the text isn't visible
> [image]

---

now another bug that I solved is using `-90deg` intead of `90deg` to make the border to the right.
[image]

**so what I want?**

- a simple css solution,
- that makes the nav responsive to the height of the device
- with the same behavior of grid 1fr (but in my case I am using flex then rotate it)
- the text need to be always visible inside the height of the device
- don't change with the width, change only with the height
- gaps don't get bigger a lot
- border line need to be on the right

[image]

ok. now here my code:

```css
:root {
  --height: 3rem;
  --triangle-width: 1rem;
  --bg: #ccc;
  --angle: 20deg;
  --text-color: black;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  gap: var(--triangle-width);
  color: var(--text-color);
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 var(--triangle-width);
  transform: rotate(-90deg) translate(-45vw, -45vw);
}

nav::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  background: var(--text-color);
  height: 0.2rem;
  width: 100%;
}

nav div {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  height: var(--height);
  width: calc(100% - (var(--triangle-width) * 2));
  position: relative;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

nav div:hover {
  background-color: var(--bg);
}

nav div:hover::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: calc(-1 * (var(--triangle-width) / 2));
  height: var(--height);
  width: var(--triangle-width);
  background-color: var(--bg);
  transform: skewX(calc(-1 * var(--angle)));
}

nav div:hover::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: calc(-1 * (var(--triangle-width) / 2));
  height: var(--height);
  width: var(--triangle-width);
  background-color: var(--bg);
  transform: skewX(var(--angle));
}

nav div::before,
nav div::after {
  z-index: -1;
}

nav::before {
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div>instagram</div>
  <div>microsoft</div>
  <div>facebook</div>
  <div>linkedin</div>
  <div>youtube</div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would simplify your code and only consider 4 properties to rotate and correctly set the height of your element. I also updated your HTML code for a better semantic markup

```css
:root {
  --height: 3rem;
  --triangle-width: 1rem;
  --bg: #ccc;
  --text-color: black;
}
nav {
  display: flex;
  color: var(--text-color);
  border-bottom: 0.2rem solid var(--text-color); 
  position: absolute;
  min-width: fit-content;  /* in case we have small height */
  /* you need the below */
  inset: 0 auto auto var(--triangle-width);
  width: calc(100vh - 2*var(--triangle-width));
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  transform: rotate(-90deg) translate(calc(-100% - var(--triangle-width)));
  /**/
}
nav ul {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: space-around;
  gap: var(--triangle-width);
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
nav ul li {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  min-height: var(--height);
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  cursor: pointer;
}

nav ul li:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  inset: 0 calc(-1*var(--triangle-width));
  clip-path: polygon(var(--triangle-width) 0, calc(100% - var(--triangle-width)) 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
}

nav ul li:hover:before {
  background: var(--bg);
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>instagram</li>
    <li>microsoft</li>
    <li>facebook</li>
    <li>linkedin</li>
    <li>youtube</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: thanks, you solved the positioning bug!

Comment: but how can I solve the bug of gap became bigger, and text go outside the viewport of device?

Comment: no sorry, tried now with bigger full screen code snippet, work just fine!!!! thanks

Comment: @stackdeveloper made a few updates as well, refrech the apge to see

Comment: is not working anymore, maybe the last edit. now there is a lot of space on the top, and all icon go to on the bottom

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EVg5e.jpg here the image of the bug

Comment: just 10 minutes ago, works fine, now is not working

Comment: @stackdeveloper fixed, I update the HTML to make it better for semantic, I missed one CSS instruction on the road

Comment: @stackdeveloper I made a last edit, all should be fine now

Comment: yes, is correct :)